# Swift class in Objective C Project

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm having problems executing some Swift code in an existing ObjC project. This is my first attempt at Swift so I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

I have added my new swift file to my project - this process generated the bridging header. So now I have the following:

#### bridging-header file

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers 
//  that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#import "historyViewController.h"
```

In my swift file I have the following test class and function:

```
import Foundation

@objc class Hello: NSObject {
    func sayHello() {
        print("Hi There")
    }
}
```

In my *historyViewController.m* file I have the following

```
#import "xx-Bridging-Header.h"
```

In my *historyViewController.h* file I have the following

```
@class Hello;
```

How do I actually go about executing the `sayHello` function from within my *historyViewController.m* file? I've tried `[Hello sayHello];` - but get 'no known class method'.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is only that you are calling `sayHello` as if it were a *class* method, but `sayHello` is declared as an *instance* method. So:

```
[[Hello new] sayHello];
```

Comment: Or the other way round: Make it a type method (aka class method).

Comment: How do I make it a type method?

Comment: When I do [[Hello new] sayHello]; I get error - Receiver 'Hello' for class message is a forward declaration

Comment: Wow, you're quite rude. Why you took the time I don't know.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'll delete that comment. But when you deleted `@class Hello;` how did things go? This is very easy stuff so it's a pity you're having so much difficulty getting started with it.